# How to change this RNN text classification code to text generation?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, text-classification

I have this code to do text classification with TensorFlow RNN, but how to change it to do text generation instead?

The following text classification has 3D input, but 2D output. Should it be changed to 3D input and 3D output for text generation? and how?

The example data are:

```
t0      t1      t2
british gray    is => cat (y=0)
0       1       2
white   samoyed is => dog (y=1)
3       4       2
```

For classification feeding "british gray is" results in "cat". What I wish to get is feeding "british" should result in the next word "gray".

```
import tensorflow as tf;
tf.reset_default_graph();

#data
'''
t0      t1      t2
british gray    is => cat (y=0)
0       1       2
white   samoyed is => dog (y=1)
3       4       2 
'''
Bsize = 2;
Times = 3;
Max_X = 4;
Max_Y = 1;

X = [[[0],[1],[2]], [[3],[4],[2]]];
Y = [[0],           [1]          ];

#normalise
for I in range(len(X)):
  for J in range(len(X[I])):
    X[I][J][0] /= Max_X;

for I in range(len(Y)):
  Y[I][0] /= Max_Y;

#model
Inputs   = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [Bsize,Times,1]);
Expected = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [Bsize,      1]);

#single LSTM layer
#'''
Layer1   = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(20);
Hidden1  = Layer1(Inputs);
#'''

#multi LSTM layers
'''
Layers = tf.keras.layers.RNN([
  tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(30), #hidden 1
  tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(20)  #hidden 2
]);
Hidden2 = Layers(Inputs);
'''

Weight3  = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([20,1], -1,1));
Bias3    = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([   1], -1,1));
Output   = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Hidden1,Weight3) + Bias3);

Loss     = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(Expected-Output));
Optim    = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-1);
Training = Optim.minimize(Loss);

#train
Sess = tf.Session();
Init = tf.global_variables_initializer();
Sess.run(Init);

Feed = {Inputs:X, Expected:Y};
for I in range(1000): #number of feeds, 1 feed = 1 batch
  if I%100==0: 
    Lossvalue = Sess.run(Loss,Feed);
    print("Loss:",Lossvalue);
  #end if

  Sess.run(Training,Feed);
#end for

Lastloss = Sess.run(Loss,Feed);
print("Loss:",Lastloss,"(Last)");

#eval
Results = Sess.run(Output,Feed);
print("\nEval:");
print(Results);

print("\nDone.");
#eof
```

Comment: Do you mean with it's current state? Or are you ok with retraining it?

Comment: @Recessive i mean how to get the next word instead of class, for example, feeding "british", i should be able to get "gray" instead of feeding "british gray is" to get "cat"

Comment: The example data is confusing, but it looks incompatible. Since you didn't answer I'll assume you are ok with retraining the network, in that case the best course of action is identical input and output dimensions, probably 1d. To do this you can take all the words in the training data and use them as a very big 1 hot vector for input and output. As an example, say you had the words `['hello', 'hi','is','that','yes']` then your input would be 1d with length 5, and to input `'hello'` you would input a 1 at index 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to switch it (the code) to do text generation task, use 3D input (X) and 3D labels (Y) as in the source code below:

Source code:

```
import tensorflow as tf;
tf.reset_default_graph();

#data
'''
t0       t1       t2
british  gray     is  cat
0        1        2   (3)  <=x
1        2        3        <=y
white    samoyed  is  dog
4        5        2   (6)  <=x
5        2        6        <=y 
'''
Bsize = 2;
Times = 3;
Max_X = 5;
Max_Y = 6;

X = [[[0],[1],[2]], [[4],[5],[2]]];
Y = [[[1],[2],[3]], [[5],[2],[6]]];

#normalise
for I in range(len(X)):
  for J in range(len(X[I])):
    X[I][J][0] /= Max_X;

for I in range(len(Y)):
  for J in range(len(Y[I])):
    Y[I][J][0] /= Max_Y;

#model
Input    = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [Bsize,Times,1]);
Expected = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [Bsize,Times,1]);

#single LSTM layer
'''
Layer1   = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(20);
Hidden1  = Layer1(Input);
'''

#multi LSTM layers
#'''
Layers = tf.keras.layers.RNN([
  tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(30), #hidden 1
  tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(20)  #hidden 2
],
return_sequences=True);
Hidden2 = Layers(Input);
#'''

Weight3  = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([20,1], -1,1));
Bias3    = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([   1], -1,1));
Output   = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Hidden2,Weight3) + Bias3); #sequence of 2d * 2d

Loss     = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(Expected-Output));
Optim    = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-1);
Training = Optim.minimize(Loss);

#train
Sess = tf.Session();
Init = tf.global_variables_initializer();
Sess.run(Init);

Feed   = {Input:X, Expected:Y};
Epochs = 10000;

for I in range(Epochs): #number of feeds, 1 feed = 1 batch
  if I%(Epochs/10)==0: 
    Lossvalue = Sess.run(Loss,Feed);
    print("Loss:",Lossvalue);
  #end if

  Sess.run(Training,Feed);
#end for

Lastloss = Sess.run(Loss,Feed);
print("Loss:",Lastloss,"(Last)");

#eval
Results = Sess.run(Output,Feed).tolist();
print("\nEval:");
for I in range(len(Results)):
  for J in range(len(Results[I])):
    for K in range(len(Results[I][J])):
      Results[I][J][K] = round(Results[I][J][K]*Max_Y);
#end for i      
print(Results);

print("\nDone.");
#eof
```